# operation templates?

Tags: c++

Is there a way to do something like this pseudo code (btw i know I cant use templates to do this, it is just for illustration) :

```
template<operator Op>
int operator Op (int a, number b) {
    return (a Op to_int(b));
}
```

You get the gist right. Currently I use alot of overloading to do this, but it is too repetitive. I tried doing something with void* pointers (for the function args) and eventually passing runtime-typeid info but the code seemed too involved.
Any other solution....

thanx for your ideas

I'm trying to write less overridden methods... I have to write 12 just for +,-,/,* ..not to mention the rest of the op's I want to override.

Let me give you more concrete example what I want to repeat less :

```
scalar operator Op (scalar a, string b) {..Op..}
scalar operator Op (scalar a, number b) {..Op..}
scalar operator Op (scalar a, scalar b) {..Op..}
```

the handling is different but when I have to do the calculation inside it is the same except the Operator is different. So instead of doing 12 overloaded methods I will do 3. 
The code inside could be abit longer than what was my first illustration, sorry.

I think I found a solution :
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton-Nackman_trick
OR the boost libs nevsan pointed out.

Comment: i may be a noob but this just looks wrong on many levels. from what i can gather of what you're trying to achieve then no you can't do it it's like saying you want to make function names at compilation.

Comment: Would it be reasonable to add an implicit conversion to `int` in `number`?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore [The more you know](http://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nbc+the+more+you+know)

Comment: You can't "deduce function names" in C++, like this pseudo situation: `template <function F> int F(int a, int b) { return a + b; }`, `int c = foo(1, 2);` (deduces `F = foo`?!)

Comment: -- "The more you know, the less you remember" :)

Comment: Please don't post answers as part of your question.

Answer (score 4):

I think you could help do this with a macro:

```
#define DEFINE_NUMBER_OP(op) \
int operator op (int a, number b) { \
    return (a op to_int(b));\
}\
\
int operator op (number a, int b) { \
    return (to_int(a) op tb);\
}\
\
int operator op (number a, number b) { \
    return <generic code to do op on numbers>;\
}\
\
```

Then you use it:
DEFINE_NUMBER_OP(+);

But I would instead consider rethinking your approach. *Don't* automatically let your users mix different types but force them to explicitly indicate the math they want. Only support `number OP number` operators rather than implicitly supporting a bunch of int operations.

EDIT: To elaborate a bit more, when you start supporting a lot of implicit operators it's really easy to make a mistake and perform an unwanted operation which could takes hours or days to debug, versus writing code one time with explicit indication as to your intent (remember you only have to write your intention once and people can clearly see your meaning every time they read the code until the end of time).

Comment: You see this sort of thing in Boost code; in `const_string`, for example. +1

Answer (score 1):

In the end, you're defining a function name. So there's no method to do this in the language strictly.

This is something that could probably be accomplished by using the preprocessor though.

Answer (score 1):

#### Disclaimer - I'm against this:

```
struct A
{
    operator int() {return 0;}
};
```

The cast will be implicit when you attempt to do operations like `1+a` (where `a` is an `A`).

Plus, you no longer need the `to_int` function.

### Don't do it

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not help your situation, but checkout boost [operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/utility/operators.htm).

Comment: This actually won't work because his return type is `int`, not `Number`.

Answer (score 1):

This might actually be a task for a macro:

```
#define DEFINE_OPERATOR_( op, res, lhs, rhs, ltr, rtr ) \
   res operator##op( lhs l, rhs r ) { return ltr op rtr; }
#define DEFINE_OPERATOR_L( op, res, lhs, rhs ) \
   DEFINE_OPERATOR_( op, res, lhs, rhs, to_int(lhs), rhs )
#define DEFINE_OPERATOR_R( op, res, lhs, rhs ) \
   DEFINE_OPERATOR_( op, res, lhs, rhs, lhs, to_int(rhs) )
#define DEFINE_OPERATOR_BOTH( op, mytype, othertype ) \
   DEFINE_OPERATOR_L( op, othertype, mytype, othertype ) \
   DEFINE_OPERATOR_R( op, othertype, othertype, mytype )

DEFINE_OPERATOR_BOTH( *, number, int );
DEFINE_OPERATOR_BOTH( /, number, int );
//...

#undef DEFINE_OPERATOR_BOTH
#undef DEFINE_OPERATOR_L
#undef DEFINE_OPERATOR_R
#undef DEFINE_OPERATOR_
```